# ng-repeat based based on nested items

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

Based on the data below, and assuming there are more cars and more firebase user id's associated with specific cars. How would I ng-repeat only the car data that matches the current user. Example: if I was signed in and my Firebase.uid was simplelogin:26, how would I ng-repeat the car data that had my Firebase.uid within it? So in this case it would only display the Honda.

I have read that the way you organize Firebase data is really important so I'm not sure if this is formatted ideally, either way I would like to know if this is possible the way it's currently formatted. I still learning all this and can't seem to figure this out. Any insight would be great, thank you!

## html

```
<h1>MyCars</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="car in cars">     
      <p>Make: {{ car.type }}</p>
      <p>Year: {{ car.year }}</p>
      <p>color: {{ car.color }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**JSON**

```
"cars": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "type": "Honda",
      "year": "2008",
      "color":"red",
      "simplelogin:26": {
       "name":"ted"
     },
      "simplelogin:32": {
       "name":"ted"
      }
    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
      "type": "Chevy",
      "year": "2006",
      "color":"white",
      "simplelogin:16": {
       "name":"ted"
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't included the definition of `cars` in your data, or how you've inserted it into `$scope` (or any code that is helpful, really). Please include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your attempt thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an ideal data structure. If cars indeed have a 1:1 relationship with users, as the data suggests, then one should simply store them by user and then query that specific user id:

```
{
  "cars": {
      "ted": {
         ...
      }
  }
}
```

Now querying cars by user is extremely simple:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
$scope.cars = $firebaseArray(ref.child('cars/<USER ID>'));
```

If cars cannot be split by user, because they have an n:1 relationship, then [a query](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) can provide the same functionality (make sure you [index them on the server](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html)):

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
var query = ref.child('cars').orderByChild('name').equalTo('ted');
$scope.cars = $firebaseArray(query);
```

If you want to have an n:n relationship, then indexing users to cars is more appropriate:

```
"cars": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "type": "Honda",
      "year": "2008",
      "color":"red"
     },
     ...
},

"owners": {
   "ted": {
      "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": true,
      ...
   }
}
```

Fetching cars for a given user is now a bit more difficult, but still not unreasonable:

```
angular.factory('CachedCarList', function() {
  // a simple cache of Firebase objects looked up by key
  // in this case, a list of cars that have an n:n relationship to users
  var carsRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/cars");
  var carsLoaded = {};

  return {
    get: function(carId) {
      if( !carsLoaded.hasOwnProperty(carId) ) {
        carsLoaded[cardId] = $firebaseObject(carsRef.child(carId));
      }
      return carsLoaded[carId];
    },
    destroy: function(carId) {
      angular.forEach(carsLoaded, function(car) {
        car.$destroy();
      });
      carsLoaded = {};
    }
  }
});

angular.factory('CarList', function($firebaseArray, CachedCarList) {
   var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");

   var CarsIndexed = $firebaseArray.$extend({
     '$$added': function(snapshot) {
        // when something is added to the index, synchronize the actual car data
        // we use the $loaded promise because returning it here will make AngularFire
        // wait for that data to load before triggering added events and Angular's compiler
        return CachedCarList.get(snapshot.key()).$loaded();
     },

     '$$updated': function(snapshot) {
        return false; // our cars update themselves, nothing to do here
     }
   });

   return function(userId) {
      // when a list of cars is requested for a specific user, we return an CarsIndexed
      // than synchronizes on the index, and then loads specific cars by referencing their
      // data individually
      return new CarsIndexed(ref.child('owners/'+userId));
   }
});
```

And [firebase-util's NormalizedCollection](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/toolbox/NormalizedCollection/) can help make this process much simpler:

```
angular.factory('CarList', function($firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
  return function(userId) {
    var nc new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
      ref.child('owners/' + userId),
      ref.child('cars')
    ).select('cars.type', 'cars.year', 'cars.color')
    return $firebaseArray(nc.ref());
  }
});
```

The Firebase [Angular guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) covers many topics like this one, and also introduces a bindings library to handle syncing remote/local data on your behalf.

Also, many topics such as data structures, indexing many-to-one or many-to-many relationships, et al are covered in the Firebase docs. I'd highly recommend reading [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) front to back before going any further.

Comment: Thanks you for the thorough response and suggestions. Looks like to do it right I'm going to have to stop and (rethink/learn more) before I proceed. This seems to add another level of complexity I haven't dealt with yet, but I guess now is as good of a time as any to dive deeper. lol, thanks.

Comment: Joining data is difficult in NoSQL. Firebase will continue to make this simpler as we iterate. For now, there is some work involved in learning the techniques, but they are fairly simple once you've grasped them.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the properties on an object in `ng-repeat` using the syntax `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in cars">
        <p>Make: {{ value.type }}</p>
        <p>Year: {{ value.year }}</p>
        <p>color: {{ value.color }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this alone didn't do the trick I also had to add: (ng-show="value.hasOwnProperty(Firebase.uid)), but it steered me in the right direction. Thank you!